# Change adapter based on sort criteria

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm building an application which needs to perform http request or sql request based on a sort criteria.

When the sort criteria is `Popularity` or `Vote` I call an API. When the criteria is `Favorite` I use a SQLite database.

I currently have a custom adapter which extends `BaseAdapter` to fetch data from http request. I also use this adapter for sql request but I have to manually rerun the sql request and notify the adapter on changes.

For sql request, I would like to use a cursor adapter in order to easily use some features like loaders.

**My question is :** Is it possible / Is it a good practice to have two adapters and to switch them based on sort criteria ?

If no, what should I do ? I have some ideas like build a custom AsyncTaskLoader or save the http results into the database with a `isFavorite` entry so I will be able to only use the CursorAdapter.

Comment: use one adapter: `[Simple]CursorAdapter` and a custom `ContentProvider`

Comment: but it supposes that all my data is in the database. I currently only have favorites items in my database.

Comment: no difference... you can either access db or your API in the custom `ContentProvider`

Comment: I did'nt know that. Thanks a lot, I will try it tonight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible / Is it a good practice to have two adapters and to
>   switch them based on sort criteria ?

Why would you want two adapters? What you really need is to let your Activity/Fragment implements the  `CursorLoader` interface, and use it in conjunction with a subclass of `CursorAdapter`. After your http request returns with the new data, you update your database and notify on the specific `Uri`. Android will provide to re-query your database. `onLoadFinish` you will only have to swap the cursor

Comment: I do not want to save all the data into the database. I just want to save data into the database when the user push the favorite button.

Comment: you can still use the content provider and the cursor loader mechanism. Update will store the response in the runtime memory, and query can return a cursor that you can generate manually

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it tonight.

Comment: it seems quite difficult (but not impossible) to create a new cursor (there are 42 abstract methods to override). Is there an easier solution ?

Comment: yep, you can use a [MatrixCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html)

Comment: Thanks, you saved my night